# why is MongoDbB not running and not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

i installed MongoDB compass and when i try to connect with hostname localhost ,Port: 27017
i receive this error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017.
I also looked in Task manager and MongoDB was not running. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB compass is only a client. you should install the mongo community edition (for development setup) and then use compass client to access it.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB compass is graphical user interface (GUI) for the actual mongoDB. That is to say, you need an actual mongoDB running in order to be able to interact with the data through the GUI.

Once you have the database install, you can start it by typing the command mongo in the shell. There after you should be able to return to mongoDB compass and view the data in you database (I should mention, I'm assuming that you're running on the default port and on your local machine).